# Getting the wrong date in the alldayevent and Recurring Event Date SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, jsom

I am getting the wrong date with JSOM/Jquery while converting to ISO format, If I get the today's date, then it will add a day and it shows the next day date.

**Recurring Event**-It shows date plus one added day. 
Eg- If the date 5th October 2016, it shows the 6th October 2016.
So how to fix it?
I have used below code to convert-

var info = timeZone.get_information();
var offset = (info.get_bias() + info.get_daylightBias()) / 60.0;
var serverendDate = new Date(new Date(date).getTime() - offset * 3600 * 1000).toISOString();

Comment: I have used this and getting correct date- date.toISOString();
Is it correct way do the same?